# Select from SQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a database and want to select from mysql a result which could not succeed after one month please help me it would be really appreciated!

My Database Table looks like below and Name =  Customer

```
Id  customer_id     customer_name       Date            Books_bought
1           1           Alex            08.06.2017      HarryPotter1 
2           1           Alex            08.06.2017      Harry Potter2
3           1           Alex            09.06.2017      PHP 7
4           2           Sam             10.06.2017      SQL
```

I want to display the following:

1. What books Alex bought on 08.06.2017 - Harry Potter1 and Harry Potter 2
2. In another table row that Alex on 09.06.2017 bought only PHP 7
3. In another table row another customer Sam on 10.06.2017 bought SQL

However, the result return all books for one customer Alex which has customer_id=1 and the reset users result are the same
My current html and php Table looks like below:

```
Id  customer_id    customer_name        Date            Books_bought

1           1           Alex            08.06.2017      HarryPotter1 
                                                        Harry Potter2
                                                        PHP 7
                                                        SQL
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
2          1            Alex            09.06.2017      HarryPotter1 
                                                        Harry Potter2
                                                        PHP 7
                                                        SQL

-------------------------------------------------------------------------
3          2            Sam             10.06.2017      HarryPotter1 
                                                        Harry Potter2
                                                        PHP 7
                                                        SQL
```

Comment: Do you have the query that you used to get your current output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want to `GROUP BY` *customer* and *date*; and I guess that you want to concatenate the books.

This would do it:

```
 SELECT
     customer_id, customer_name, `Date`, 
     GROUP_CONCAT(`Books_bought` ORDER BY `Books_bought` SEPARATOR ', ') AS books
 FROM
     t
 GROUP BY
     customer_id, customer_name , `Date`
 ORDER BY
     `Date`, customer_id, customer_name ;
```

```
 customer_id | customer_name | Date       | books
 ----------: | :------------ | :--------- | :--------------------------
           1 | Alex          | 08.06.2017 | Harry Potter2, HarryPotter1
           1 | Alex          | 09.06.2017 | PHP 7
           2 | Sam           | 10.06.2017 | SQL
```

Check:

- [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/group_concat/)
- [`GROUP BY`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql-99/group-by-clause/)

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=eb3e9b8b49da6c38aa6421f3050637d7)*

Comment: Dear Joanolo, I really thank you for the perfect answer I have ever received but your solution only works in maria db but I use phpmyadmin sql and I recieve this error:

Comment: SQL query: Documentation


SELECT
    customer_id, customer_name, `Date`, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(`Books_bought` ORDER BY `Books_bought` SEPARATOR ', ') AS books
FROM
    t
GROUP BY
    customer_id, `Date`
ORDER BY
    `Date`, customer_id LIMIT 0, 25
MySQL said: Documentation

#1055 - Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'cc.t.customer_name' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: if you please correct the query it would be really apperciated, Thank you very much you are the best!

Comment: Done, added `customer_name` to the `GROUP BY`... now that's SQL standardish...

Comment: I knew it, you can do it, you are the best! i don't know how to thank you best of Luck! really apperciated!